# error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0:

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, electron

I am trying to get started with electron to build desktop apps, and I ran into the following error while trying to start the application.

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this occur after in ran the `electron main.js` via bash on my windows 10 device.

Electron was installed as follow:

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron

Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

```
> electron main.js

[8002:0814/084446:FATAL:render_sandbox_host_linux.cc(40)] Check failed: 0 == shutdown(renderer_socket_, SHUT_RD). shutdown: Invalid argument
#0 0x000001e098ce <unknown>
#1 0x000001e1f4db <unknown>
#2 0x000001e1fa9d <unknown>
#3 0x000002892fc2 <unknown>
#4 0x00000265e599 <unknown>
#5 0x000002664b5f <unknown>
#6 0x00000265dc36 <unknown>
#7 0x000001204157 <unknown>
#8 0x000001202c30 <unknown>
#9 0x0000033a9470 main
#10 0x7fe5ec701f45 __libc_start_main
#11 0x000000575039 <unknown>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0` and install an X server for Windows, such as [xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Comment: Thanks what do you mean by x server for windows, and why would such task be required out of curiosity?

Comment: You need an X server because you're running the Linux version of Electron, which uses GTK, and in order to use GTK you need an X server of some kind to be able to display the GTK windows and widgets.

Comment: thanks, but for some odd reason (despite restarting my computer and having install libgtk and xming the issue persist ) /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You're just missing more packages. Just search for the library name with `dpkg -S libXtst.so` for example or search on google to find the appropriate package name.

Comment: OK thank you. I followed your advice and search and install any package until the error of missing libraries stoped. Now an unexpected error is throw (i have added an update under my initial post). Everything run smoothly when i run it from ubuntu, but lots of adjustment to get it to run on windows

Comment: That's not surprising, the new Linux subsystem on Windows is new and Microsoft is still working on it. Why not just use the Windows build of Electron instead?

Comment: what do you mean by the windows build of electron?

Comment: Weird that you have to faff on with dependencies on linux I thought the package managers are supposed sort all that out.

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux x64 -> 32 bit package:

```
yaourt -S lib32-libgtkhtml
```

Note for me :)